# Create a conditional or selective rule using Clips

Tags: clips

I hope you are doing very well? I am a beginner in regards to CLIPS.
I have a graph of several nodes (start nodes (input) and of end nodes (output).
I want to create a rule in the case where I have the number of input is equal to output, the rule must help me choose between several combinations (start and end nodes) the shortest path for each combination.

Another rule can be added with the same rule before, if I have the number of input is greater than the number of output or the opposite. After selecting between the combination it is also necessary to take into consideration the input or the output and to derive it towards the nearest point?

the combination result if i have 3 input and 2 output

- a to d cost 10
- b to d cost 7
- c to d cost 7.6
- a to e cost 7
- b to e cost 5.8
- c to e cost 4.7

As final result i hope to get

- 5 to 3 cost 7
- 6 to 2 cost 4.7
- 1 to 2 cost 7

(the same reasoning if we have the output more than the output)

thank you for your Help

Comment: It's not clear how you're getting your results from your input.

Comment: my input and output it is simply from a started node to a ended node . it clear now or i put the code and the result ??

Comment: No, it's not clear how you're getting your results from your input. 5 to 3 cost 7? How did you derive 5? How did you derive 3? How did you derive 7?

Comment: Ok i understand you i will ask another question and put the hole programme .